# jquery accordion arrows

Tags: jquery, accordion

How can i add two arrows to mjquery accordion?  One when its closed and one when its active?

Comment: which version of the accordion are you using, or have you rolled your own?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look here: [Accordian w/Custom Icons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#custom-icons)